# How long does the teleporter particle effect last?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

I love teleporters.  They're convenient on nearly every map, whether you're attacking or defending.  And secret teleporters are the best, because as long as they're secret, they're safe.

But, a tell-tale sign that there is a teleporter somewhere nearby is the lingering particle effect that clings to a class aftere emerging from a teleporter, and the last thing I want to do to my good ol' Engineering buddy is to reveal the location of his hidden (rebel) base.

So to sum up, **how long after exiting a teleporter is the particle effect on a character model visible to enemies?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Teleporters:

> > Players who have recently teleported are surrounded by a distinctive, glowing particle effect for eighteen seconds after teleporting.

Comment: Nice, quick answer. :)

Comment: I believe the effect also decreases in intensity over time after the player exits the teleporter.